# ¿Como acceder a una matrix con una 'id'?

Tags: c, matrices, manejo-de-memoria, math

### El problema:

Tengo una array de dos dimensiones. Con diferentes valores en eje X e Y. (O sea, la primera dimensión de la array es diferente a la segunda). El caso es, que necesito averiguar como acceder a una posición X e Y, a partir de una id, la cual sale de contar las posiciones de la array, como si solo tuvieran una dimensión.

#### Por poner un ejemplo:

```c
#include <stdio.h>


float get_value_at(float mat[][], int id) {
    /* mágia*/
    return value;
}

int main() {
    float mat[2][4] = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        {5, 6, 7, 8},
    };
    
    float value0 = get_value_at(mat, 5);
    printf("%f\n", value0); // Mostrará 6.

    float value1 = get_value_at(mat, 0);
    printf("%f\n", value1); // Mostrará 1.

    return 0;
}
```

El valor de la variable `valor0` será  6, porque al empezar a contar desde cero, la posición de la matriz que contiene 6 queda en la quinta posición (según el id).

```
valores:    {1, 2, 3, 4}
id:          0  1  2  3
            
valores:    {5, 6, 7, 8}
id:          4  [5]  6  7
```

### He probado:

He probado a usar esto:

```c
float get_value_at(float mat[][], int id) {
    int x = id % 2; // Uso 2, porque es la longitud del eje X
    int y = id / 4; // Uso 4, porque es la longitud del eje Y
    return mat[x][y]; // No funciona correctamente
}
```

Esto no funciona, ya que las longitudes X e Y son diferentes, esta función solo hace su trabajo cuando, la matriz, tiene dimensiones iguales para los dos ejes.

#### NOTA:

Tampoco quiero hacer eso aunque el resultado sea precisamente lo que busco:

```c
printf("%f\n", ((float*)mat)[5]);
```

Comment: Podrías hacer un casting de `float **mat` (que es tu matriz) a `float *mat`, y luego sumar la cantidad de posiciones que vas a avanzar

Comment: para operar una matriz de N dimensiones, debes usar un `for` por cada una de ellas

Comment: ¿A que te refieres, exactamente?

Comment: Si uso un bucle el programa perdería rendimiento, cuando esto, se puede hacer con una operación matematica.

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodrigo estas en C(ya es muy rapido), el rendimiento para algo tan simple como esto solo importa si estas en programacion competitiva, si no sabes usar punteros(en especifico aritmetrica de punteros) no vas a poder hacer lo que quieres. Usa los bucles y despues de aprender como manipular matrices vas por el premio mayor que es lo que quieres, aun asi no entiendo que buscas hacer con el programa, asi que no puedo publicarte una respuesta

Comment: @Egon Stetmann si la array fuese de `N * M` dimensiones y `N == M`. Si haces lo siguiente: `int x = id % N;` y `int y = id / N;` y después retornas `return mat[x][y];` da exactamente el resultado que busco, lo único es que solo funciona con matrices `N * M`, si `N == M`. Por eso pregunto, como se puede hacer esto cuando `N != M`

Comment: @Egon Stetmann por dar mas contexto, prueba esto. Creo que funciona, si no me equivoco: https://onlinegdb.com/B1t4bCC4v

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodrigo Te aseguro que no verás ninguna diferencia significativa si llegaras a recorrer el array con bucles.

Comment: @MrDave1999 Quiero recorrerla en tiempo real, concretamente estoy haciendo un videojuego y no quiero recorrerla de golpe. Quiero esperar a que pase cierto tiempo hasta poder avanzar. ¿Eso afectará a mi rendimiento?

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodrigo es dificil decirte si eso afectaria al rendimiento o no, tocaria hacer benchmarks para ver que solucion es mas rapida.. Por cierto, no olvides de marcar la respuesta que resolvio tu problema..

Comment: Si vas a optar por esa solucion, te recomiendo usar macros, asi evitas la llamada de una funcion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La operación aritmética debería quedar de esta forma:

```c
//"4" es el tamaño de columnas..
mat[id / 4][id % 4]
```

El código completo sería:

```c
float get_value_at(float mat[][4], int id) 
{
    return mat[id / 4][id % 4];
}
  

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    float mat[2][4] = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        {5, 6, 7, 8},
    };
    
    float value0 = get_value_at(mat, 5);
    printf("%f\n", value0); // Mostrará 6.

    float value1 = get_value_at(mat, 0);
    printf("%f\n", value1); // Mostrará 1.
    return 0;
}
```

El código lo puedes ejecutar en [onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/rkLr6qkHD).

Podrías ahorrarte en definir una función si creas una macro:

```c
#define N 2
#define M 4

#define get_value_at(mat, id) mat[id / M][id % M]

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    float mat[N][M] = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        {5, 6, 7, 8},
    };
    
    float value0 = get_value_at(mat, 5);
    printf("%f\n", value0); // Mostrará 6.

    float value1 = get_value_at(mat, 0);
    printf("%f\n", value1); // Mostrará 1.
    return 0;
}
```

El preprocesador expandirá este código:

```c
float value0 = get_value_at(mat, 5);
```

a

```c
float value0 = mat[5 / M][5 % M];
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar un VLA.

```
float get_value_at(int N, int M, 
                   float mat[N][M], int id) {
   return mat[id/M][id%M];
}

int main()
{
   ....
   float value0 = get_value_at(2, 4, mat, 5);
   ....
}
```

Comment: Solo para completar, los VLA es opcional a partir de C11, así que dependerá del compilador.